# How to add event to a date in fullcalender on clicking a date

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, fullcalendar

I am using fullcalender. Presently adding event to a date by using drag option.Now I need to add event by clicking on particular date.

Is there any option?

Comment: Can you show any code of what you have so far in the question? (Use the [edit] button).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this code in the [documentation](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/dayClick/):

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
        alert('Clicked on: ' + date.format());
        alert('Coordinates: ' + jsEvent.pageX + ',' + jsEvent.pageY);
        alert('Current view: ' + view.name);

        // change the day's background color just for fun
        $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
    }
});
```

**Edit:** The `dayClick` is what I believe you're looking for.

Comment: This works when clicking on event. I need code to add event while clicking on particular date

Comment: @sandeep I apologize, I realized that a minute or so after I posted it. I've updated my answer to `dayClick` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I found this code in the youtube Utphala lessons:

```
$(document).on('click','.fc-day',function(){
    var date = $(this).attr('data-date');
   $.get('index.php?r=events/create',{'date':date},function(data){
     $('#modal').modal('show')
        .find('#modalContent')
        .html(data);
    });
     });
```